# Team Explorer does not detect all adds to the local workspace

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2015
Version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1 with TFS 2013 (30723.00).

Let's say my local TFS workspace is `d:\workspace`
Some of my existing projects which are not in source control are lying under `d:\projects` and I want to add them to TFS.

When I copy `Solution_A` from `d:\projects` to `d:\workspace\solution_a_team\Main`, where `solution_a_team` is the team project folder with a branch named `Main`, Team Explorer says `Detected: x add(s)` - where I'm assuming x is the number of files transferred.

What's confusing is that the number x is not consistent. Sometimes all files are detected sometimes only small percentage of files. What am I doing wrong, or what's the best way to check these folders into TFS?

Comment: Do you have a `.tfignore` file that's excluding some of the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, please check whether there are some files adding in the excluded changes. There are included changes and excluded changes in the pending changes page.
[image]

Also, it's not recommend to just copy files or projects to the workspace folder. It's not the right way to add files in source control.

If you want to add a solution in source control, just open the solution in solution explorer and right click the solution ,in the explorer select "**Add solution to source control**" and choose the location you want add to. If the solution have added in the source control, there will be a lock icon in front of it.

[image]

If you want to manually add files in version control, the simplest way you can **Drag the folders or files from Windows Explorer into the folder in Source Control Explorer** . More details please refer the link from MSDN: [Add files to the server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245454.aspx)

Moreover, you can also achieve this through [TF command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c327ca1z.aspx), or check in files through windows file explorer directly by [TFS Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/898a828a-af00-42c6-bbb2-530dc7b8f2e1).
[image]

Comment: "...Also, it's not recommend to just copy files or projects to the workspace folder. It's not the right way to add files in source control." that's what I was suspecting! Before doing this way I was actually doing like you said - open .sln in VS, right click and add to source control. But VS remembers the location of the folder where .sln was residing - which I did not want. I like the approach of adding from Windows Explorer to Source Control Explorer. Best! BTW there were no items in excluded list. And no .tfignore  file