# Impossible to reconcile file folders, local/team foundation server 2015

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I have a strange problem. I uploaded my solution to team foundation, then I branched my solution to one release and one development branch. After that was done i realized that not all my files where on tfs, I went to the Source control Explorer, right click on my project in the solution that had missing files (all on tfs) and then clicked on compare. There where 119 files localy that didn't showed up on tfs and when I pressed reconcile i got the error message shown in the picture.

[image]

As you can see frem the picture it says thet tfs can't reconcile since my files already exist on tfs. What to do?

Comment: If you edit heading, don't change the meaning of the question. Quite useless edit in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Before the reconcile, make sure your server folder have checked out.

If the folder have checked out and the reconcile still failed. For this situation, the simplest way is to add this local folders in source control manually. Detail ways and steps  you can refer this question: [Team Explorer does not detect all adds to the local workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271891/team-explorer-does-not-detect-all-adds-to-the-local-workspace/36275084#36275084)